# set window size asp vb javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Hi I have this codes so that the next page will open in a new tab on IE, however I wanted to set the size of the new tab page and disable some items. How do i do this?

```
If e.CommandName = "View" Then
        Session("VisitorReport") = hdnSelectedTab.Value
        Session("VisitID") = e.CommandArgument
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "NewTab", "window.open('ViewVisitor.aspx');", True)
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "NewTab", "window.open('ViewVisitor.aspx','','toolbar=yes,location=no,width=1050,height=750');", True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) and [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

**Note:** You can't control client functionality from the browser without user intervention, like open new window in new tab.

Comment: Thank you for your link I was able to do it. :)